# Erdős-Pósa property

Tags: graph-theory

In *Graph Theory* by Diestel op page 338, the Erdős-Pósa property is described in two different ways. A family of graphs $\mathcal H$ has the Erdős-Pósa property if...

1. ... the number of vertices in a graph needed to cover all its subgraphs in $\mathcal H$ is bounded by a function of its maximum number of disjoint subgraphs in $\mathcal H$.
2. ... there is a map $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that, given $k\in\mathbb N$ and a graph $G$, either $G$ has $k$ disjoint subgraphs in $\mathcal H$, or there is a set $U$ of at most $f(k)$ vertices in $G$ such that $G-U$ has no subgraph in $\mathcal H$.

I have difficulties to see why both should be equivalent. For me, 1. says the following:

There is a map $f:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that, given a graph $G$ and setting $k:=\max\{n\in\mathbb N\mid\text{$G$ has $n$ disjoint subgraphs in $\mathcal H$}\}$, then there is a set $U$ of at most $f(k)$ vertices in $G$ such that $G-U$ has no subgraph in $\mathcal H$.

How is this equivalent to 2.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a graph $G$ and a family $\cal H$, denote by $\mu_{\cal H}(G)$ the largest number of disjoint $\cal H$-subgraphs of $G$.

We then need to show that the following are equivalent :

(1') There is a map $f_1:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that, given a graph $G$, there is a set $U$ of at most $f_1(\mu_{\cal H}(G))$ vertices in $G$ such that $G-U$ has no subgraph in $\mathcal H$.

(2) there is a map $f_2:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that, given $k\in\mathbb N$ and a graph $G$, either $G$ has $k$ disjoint subgraphs in $\mathcal H$, or there is a set $U$ of at most $f_2(k)$ vertices in $G$ such that $G-U$ has no subgraph in $\mathcal H$.

Note that $f_1$ or $f_2$ can always be assumed to be nondecreasing without loss of generality (by taking $f_1(k)$ or $f_2(k)$ to be the smallest value satisfying the given property).

Proof of $(1')\Rightarrow(2)$, or in other words, how to construct $f_2$ from $f_1$ : if a graph $G$ does not have $k$ disjoint subgraphs, this means that $k\gt \mu_{\cal H}(G)$. By (1'), we know that there is a set $U$ of at most $f_1(\mu_{\cal H}(G))$ vertices in $G$ such that $G-U$ has no subgraph in $\mathcal H$. Now $f_1(\mu_{\cal H}(G)) \leq f_1(k)$ because $f_1$ is nondecreasing, so we see that taking $f_2=f_1$ works.

Proof of $(2)\Rightarrow(1')$, or in other words, how to construct $f_1$ from $f_2$ : if we take $k=\mu_{\cal H}(G)+1$ in (2), we see that the first alternative cannot hold, so the second necessarily holds : there is a set $U$ of at most $f_2(\mu_{\cal H}(G)+1)$ vertices in $G$ such that $G-U$ has no subgraph in $\mathcal H$. We then see that taking $f_1(t)=f_2(t+1)$ works.

Comment: Very understandable, thank you for your effort!